# Can a URL click a link within the URLs location?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-frontend

I am designing a website and would like to place a link in it that links not only to a webmd page, but also have the "leave a review" window opened up, I have placed a picture of the specific button within the webpage below, as well as the webpage.

Link to the webmd page:
https://doctor.webmd.com/doctor/leonard-forrest-79328c5d-6e1c-4a2f-9fba-051402a61477-overview

[The button I would like pressed automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyLoL.png)

Is this possible to do entirely within a hyperlink? I am able to use query strings to link to google business listings with their google review window already open, but i dont think that webmd is using query strings like that.

Comment: To answer your question, No you can't create a hyper link that goes to another website and then clicks a link. For the Google part, they have programmed into their website the ability to scan for the query string/hash tags and run functions depending on what is passed.

Comment: @TheFool, that doesn't answer the question of creating a link that when visited will go to another website and trigger a link on that page that triggers a function to load a modal.

Comment: Yes sorry, I have already revoked the flag. Seems like the comment slipped trhough.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a hyperlink that clicks anything on the destination page. Just think how much of a exploitable security flaw that would be.

If you owned the destination page, you could create a parametric url that took this action as a parameter, and automatically opened the review window via script as it received the request, but it's not the case.